# Standard technique for fiddling with power series

Tags: power-series

I will try a standard technique
for fiddling with power series.

If
$g(t)
=\sqrt{f(t)}
$,
then,
differentiating,
$g'(t)
=\frac {f'(t)}{2\sqrt{f(t)}}
=\frac {f'(t)}{2g(t)}
$
so
$2g'(t)g(t)
= f'(t)
$.

If 
$f(t)
=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n t^n
$
and
$g(t)
=\sum_{n \ge 0} b_n t^n
$,
then
$f'(t)
=\sum_{n \ge 1} na_n t^{n-1}
=\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)a_{n+1} t^{n}
$
and
$g'(t)
=\sum_{n \ge 1} nb_n t^{n-1}
=\sum_{n \ge 0} (n+1)b_{n+1} t^{n}
$.

Multiplying the series
for $g(t)$ and $g'(t)$,
and equating this
to the series for $f'(t)$
you get a recurrence
which will allow
the coefficients $b_n$
to be iteratively computed.

I try to solve an example for this method for $\sqrt(x)$ but i can't Please help?

Comment: Is your example just supposed to be $\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: yes i want for $\sqrt(x)$

Comment: The derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ does not exist at $0$, so it does not have a Taylor series centered at $x=0$, which is what you're trying to construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The product of two power series can be expressed as a single power series by the convolution product. Use that to obtain a general expression for the coefficient of $t^n$ in the power series of $2g'(t)g(t)$, and use the fact that it is equal to $(n+1)a_{n+1}.$

The derivative of $g(t)^2$, expressed as a power series, is

$$2g(t)g'(t)=2\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_it^i\sum_{j=0}^\infty(j+1)b_{j+1}t^j$$

Re-arranging indices with $i+j=n$ gives

$$2g(t)g'(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(2\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1)b_{j+1}b_{n-j}\right)t^n$$

Equating this to the expression for $f'(t)$ gives an equality of coefficients term by term

$$(n+1)a_{n+1}=2\sum_{j=0}^n(j+1)b_{j+1}b_{n-j}$$

which permits to evaluate the $b_j$ in terms of the $a_i$ recursively. The first three equations are

$$a_1=2b_0b_1$$
$$2a_2=2b_1^2+4b_2b_0$$
$$3a_3=6b_1b_2+6b_3b_0$$

*(This was a quickie, I cordially invite corrections!)*

Note that $b_0$ has to be determined independently as $\sqrt a_0$ because taking derivatives destroys information about constant terms. Also note that these (i.e., $a_0$ and $b_0$) cannot be zero because $\sqrt t$ is not analytic in 0.

Comment: please solve an example with three terms?